# Python Script is not running on the specified Ansible Automation Platform Execution Environment

Tags: python, automation, ansible, containers

I have an Ansible Playbook which has a task to run a python script. The code for the task is as follows:

tasks:

- name: run a python script
  command: python3 /home/pythonfiles/endec.py {{ operation }} {{ str }} {{ passwd }}
  register: result

The python script imports a package called "Cryptocode" which I have installed on an Execution Environment Container image that is stored on quay.io and is accessed using the Automation Platform.

When I run the playbook with the Execution Environment that has the python package installed (I checked using podman run imagename pip3 list command which does list the cryptocode package I've mentioned), an error is thrown saying that
"import cryptocode","ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cryptocode'"

However, when I pip3 install cryptocode on the execution node that runs the playbook no errors are shown.

Is there a reason why the python script is not being run inside the Execution Environment (Container Image)?
Could someone please help me fix this issue?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Possible reasons are: the package is not installed for the user you are using with Ansible or you installed it for a different Python version. The best is to use the [`pip` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/pip_module.html) inside your playbook to ensure the package is installed on the target node before trying to use it.